# Distance between two matrices with different dimensionality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00937) calculates the argmin index to the minimum distance between D-dimensional vectors by $\mathrm{k}=\operatorname{argmin}_{j}\left\|z_{e}(x)-e_{j}\right\|_{2}$ and the dimensions are $z_{e} \in R^{N\times D}$ and $e_{i} \in R^{D}, i \in 1,2, \ldots, K$. So we can get the minimum index $\in R^{N}$.

But their implementation computes the minimum distance between matrices of different dimensions by $\operatorname{argmin}\left\|z_{e}(x)-E\right\|_{2}$ and the dimensions are $z_{e} \in R^{N\times D}$ and $E \in R^{D\times K}, i \in 1,2, \ldots, K$ like below

```
distance = (z_e.pow(2).sum(1, keepdim=True)
            + emb.pow(2).sum(0, keepdim=True)
            - 2 * z_e @ emb)
```

this is like $\sum_{j}||z_{ej}||_2-2z_e E+\sum_{i}||E_i||_2$.

How do I decompose the minimum distance between matrices of different dimensions into the formula that the implementation is doing?

Answer (score 0):

The above calculation does not strictly compute the distance between the matrices, but rather the distance between the different number of vectors that construct the matrix below.

[image]

If I derived the calculation so that the number of dimensions of the vectors is the same, I got the same expression as the calculation they were doing on the source code.